# Disposing of a c# interface wrapping an IDispatch COM interface

Tags: c#, com, interface

I have implemented an IDispatch interface in C#. It in turn opens up an unmanaged COM interface which also  exposes an IDispatch interface.

```
    ~MyObject()
    {
       Logger.TraceDebug("About to clean up object");
       CleanupObject();
    }


    private void CleanupObject()
    {
        lock (lock_so)
        {
            try
            {
                if (so != null)
                {
                    Logger.TraceWarning("Releasing object");
                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(so);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            so = null;
        }

    }
```

The problem I'm having is that the Finalize is being called while the object is being used during normal execution meaning that attempts later to access the wrapped interface fail.  When I take the cleanup code out, the code works fine but will fail when the program using the code exits (I don't have debug info from the calling app but it's likely to be the wrapped interface hasn't been disposed). I'm at a loss as to how to address this issue and thinking that my understanding is incorrect. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The object is initialised in the following:

```
    private void InitialiseObject()
    {
        if (so == null)
        {
            so = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyProgID));
        }
    }
```

Then used like:

```
    public void DoSomething(string String)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (lock_so)
            {
            Object[] args = new Object[1];
            args[0] = String;
            so.GetType().InvokeMember("DoSomething", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, so, args);
            }
        }
```

The point of all this is the c# interface acts as a pass through class and is able to log information being passed from the third party application to the IDispatch interface.

Comment: Can you post how this object is being used?  Also, the full class would be nice

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why are you attempting to access the wrapped interface after you have disposed of the object? Or possibly the question can be rephrased as "Why is the object having its Finalize called before you are finished with it?"

Comment: @Chris I'm not attempting to do it - my class sits between a third party app and it's underlying interface to log information. It simply has it's methods called.

Comment: My point is that Finalize shouldn't be called until the object is not needed any more. If it is being called before that then the error is with whatever is calling it. If you can't change that though then can you detect if it is being used while disposed and reinitialize or something?

Comment: @Chris Yep I tried that. The object will be reinitialized without certain paramters set up (it's not stateless). I'd assumed it could have been some kind of garbage collection happening. Kind or reaching I know.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this? If i ware you and i would have a dispose method to free up some resource then i would implement the IDisposable interface. [Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P)

Comment: good point, I've modified the question so hopefully that should make it better. In summary, it's a pass through  interface that logs information.